# getRangeElements() returns 0 for newline selections in Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

If 20 **newlines** between 21 paragraphs are selected (newlines only selected) in a document then the below code should give length as 20, instead it gives 0, Anywhere I went wrong?
[image: Screenshot attached]

```
selectnewlines();
var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();
showAlert(selection.getRangeElements().length);

if (selection) {
    showAlert('there is selection');
    var elts = selection.getRangeElements();
    showAlert(elts.length);
    for (var i = elts.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var elt = elts[i];
        if (elt.getElement().editAsText) {
            var txt = elt.getElement().editAsText();
            //if (elt.isPartial()) {
            txt.deleteText(elt.getStartOffset(), elt.getEndOffsetInclusive());
            // }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but showAlert is not a method in Docs App Script. Have you defined it elsewhere?

Comment: Try logging the length: logger.log(selection.getRangeElements().length). What value does the log show?

Comment: I believe the problem is that newlines are not actually characters in docs. They cannot therefore be elements. Can I ask what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that newlines are not actually characters so they cannot be elements in a selection. When I run your script with a `Logger.log('text')` within the if statement, I get no result, meaning that the script does not treat the newlines as a selection. If that is right, then it makes sense that you are getting 0 as the length.

I wrote an add-on that deals with newlines, so if you give me an idea of what you want to do with your selected newlines, I might be able to tell you how to do it. For example, do you just want to count the number of newlines in a longer text selection?